# Javascript IE6/7/8 change input type

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

The following javascript snippet will change the type of an INPUT, for instance from text to password. It's being used to allow users to display their password on-screen when typing it in:

```
document.save_form.password_confirm.type= 'text';
...
document.save_form.password_confirm.type= 'password';
```

This works great in FF/Chrome but in IE6/7/8 I'm getting a "This command is not supported" error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type is read-only in Internet Explorer (at least 6, anyway), so it's just not directly possible.  As a workaround, I've had a hidden input field of the type I wanted, then when I need to switch the type, hid the old one and made the other one visible.  Not as clean, but unfortunately just changing the type as far as I know isn't possible.

An alternative method would be to use the JavaScript DOM to replace the field with the replaceChild function of a node.

Comment: Did something similar with jquery using `prependTo` for a new field with the correct type while removing the old field.