# HTML/CSS/JS: How to force browser to save password from a non-'password' type input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication, passwords

The thing is that I have two values which are similar to a username and password, but are actually 2 randomly generated GUID's that users use to login to a website I made - they are not really a username and password, but with the GUIDs I try to replicate this combination.

Usually browsers ask you if you want to save the provided login values when seeing the type='password' attribute for an  element. However, a type='password' attribute would make typing a GUID in a field rather difficult, since you can't see what you are typing.

So, how would you force or trick the browser to save a username/password combination without using the type="password" attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: How high are your security requirements for this. Is it a problem that the second GUID gets saved on client side as clear text? Because I think it's impossible to get this stored safely on client side ("safely" meaning the "password store" functions that the browsers have for real passwords that are at least supposedly encrypted and secured to some extent)

Comment: Not very high security requirements.

Comment: @Andrei how about storing the GUIDs in a cookie or HTML local storage?  That would be blatantly unsafe, but would do the trick. Maybe base64 encoded to not make it totally obvious....

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, I guess that's an option, although that would mean some extra work on the server side as well, and besides, it would also be interesting to know if you can somehow trick the browser into doing this for you. If I can't find anything else about solving, I might just use the cookie idea.

Comment: @Andrei I'm not sure if it's possible to write into `password` inputs via JS cross-browser. It might be. If it is, you may indeed be able to have the user fill in a text field, and copy the contents into the password field when submitting the form

Comment: @Pekka Sorry, saw your suggestion after adding the answer

Comment: Use javascript to change the type of the field at submit-time, from text to password.

Comment: @some I'm pretty sure that won't work reliably in all browsers. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, that's about it :) Happens around here @some as Pekka said, I can assure you that won't work in FF and probably won't in other browsers as well. Also, there's a chance that the browser reads the field types when it loads the page, not on submit

Comment: I just tested in IE, FF, Opera and Chrome and it didn't work. I also tried to have a password field with `style='display:none'` and that works in FF, Opera and Chrome but not in.... [drums] wait for it.... IE!. Looks like IE only asks to save a password if there are only a text and a password field. If there are more fields it won't ask...

Comment: Just tested some more: FF, Opera and Chrome lets you change the type of the field from `text` to `password` and back as many times as you want. And as always, it doesn't work that way in IE. Btw, the idea to change from `text` to `password` at submit-time actually works in Opera, if one change the field type and resubmit the form with `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Brad's answer here:

[HTML/CSS: How to make "password" input show the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004313/html-css-how-to-make-password-input-show-the-password/4004329#4004329)

Answer (score 2):

What if you save a cookie on the client side, maybe with the text encrypted and when the user comes back to the site you first look if he has a cookie saved? Of course, it's a workaround and the cookie won't be there forever, but it's an option.

I'm also thinking you might make a CSS-hidden password input and copy the content to that before submiting the form, but I'm not sure that that tricks the browser.

Comment: Setting `style='display:none'` seams to work in all browsers in the world except the browsers that come from a certain company. That certain company seams to have decided that if your have more than one text field and one password field, it isn't worth saving. Can you guess what company that is?

Comment: Oh well, same old same old. Maybe you could modify the design so you have a sort of step by step approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would think a cookie would be the easiest solution... At least until you can find something better... +1 for Claudiu's answer