# Degrading -webkit-text-security

Tags: html, css

**NOTICE:** If you are intereseted on implementing text-security feautures, I've developed a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jviotti/jquery-squared-passwords) to accomplish this.

I'm using `text-security` to style inputs:

```
input.square-password {
  -webkit-text-security: square;     
}
```

In web browsers that dont support `text-security`, password is just shown (no asterisks (****)).

I'm looking forward to degrade this functionality on browser that don't support them, by using `text-security` when is available or using standard asterisks.

The input HTML is:

```
<input class="square-password textbox" name="paymentpassword" />
```

I tried adding a `type="password"` attr:

```
<input type="password" class="square-password textbox" name="paymentpassword" />
```

But it overwrites `text-security` even on browsers that do support it.

Any workarounds? Is it posible to set asterisks to the input via `CSS` (no type="password")?

**EDIT:** text-security seems only supported by webkit.

**EDIT 2:** inputs setted as `type="password"` can't be styled with text-security. Not even with `!important` (type="email" does)

**EDIT 3:** @ryan answer works fine on:

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Opera

[Can't change input type in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618306/javascript-change-input-type-dynamically-doesnt-work-on-ie8)

Comment: Does any browser other than webkit currently support this at all? Can't find anything about it except for the `-webkit` variant...

Comment: @deceze It seems only webkit supports it. I'm fixing this code, it's not mine.

Comment: @ryan Sure, any solution or suggestion will be welcomed

Comment: So weird that it doesn't work on `type="password"`, I wonder what this is even supposed to be used for if not password-type inputs? Degrading to plain text inputs is terrible.

Comment: @WesleyMurch It's a nice feature, but it seems is not mature enought, yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was pretty quick and dirty but it works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        input{
            -webkit-text-security:square; 
            text-security:square;
        }       
    </style>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            init(); 
        }
        function init(){
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
            console.log(style);
            if(style.webkitTextSecurity){
                //do nothing
            }else{
                x.setAttribute("type","password");
            }
        }           
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="di">
        <input/>        
    </div>
</body>
```

Tested in chrome and firefox, I'm on linux so I can't test in IE.  [Jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqg8y/1/)

Comment: Seems pretty IE proof to me. If IE fails on this I would really be shocked.

Comment: In IE8, [you can't change the type of an <input> with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618306/javascript-change-input-type-dynamically-doesnt-work-on-ie8).

Comment: Great, any feedback about IE would be really appreciated, I'm on linux too

Comment: To get around the IE limitation, you can delete and recreate the element.