# -webkit-text-security compatibility

Tags: css

I have set `text-security:disc;` in the following manner but it is not working in firefox.

```
text-security:disc;
-webkit-text-security:disc;
-mox-text-security:disc;
```

I am setting these properties to `input[type='number']` field. Any suggestion?

Comment: What version are you using?? Check this browser support http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-webkit-text-security

Comment: Is there any alternative available which will work everywhere?

Comment: Yes you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822548/degrading-webkit-text-security

Comment: @Richa thanks for the link but it was not working either. I guess firefox completely deprecated/removed moz-text-security. I changed it to input[type=password] to make it work, unwillingly though.

Comment: I tried it and It works for me in Firefox.Check this fiddle in Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/Ldr07h2r/5/

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too but it is not working in Firefox 32.0

Comment: Here you go.Tested in Firefox 32.0.1 http://jsfiddle.net/Ldr07h2r/6/

Comment: @Richa you should post this as an answer ;)

Comment: The only reason this is not working is because you made a typo. It's `moz`, not `mox`

Comment: Nope. It's not working because it's been deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

```
window.onload = function() {
    init(); 
}

function init() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
    console.log(style);

    if (style.webkitTextSecurity) {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        x.setAttribute("type", "password");
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
input {
    text-security: disc;
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
    -moz-text-security: disc;
}
```

Comment: Does `x.setAttribute("type", "password");` clobber the OP's `input[type='number']` setting?

Comment: It won't trigger mobile num pad

Comment: This will only be an issue on Firefox

Answer (score 6):

**It 2022 and Firefox still doesn't support text-security**

The answers that change the input type to password have a few undesirable effects:

- Browser password suggestions and save password prompts
- Default input behaviour lost - e.g. when using type=number will show a pin pad on mobile.

There are a couple of new solutions to this problem:

1 - inputmode

```
<input type="password" inputmode="tel" />
```

This displays like a password but behaves like a tel. Seems to show mobile pin pad but still wants to save password in Firefox. Maybe this is what you want?

Inputmode has good browser coverage with the exception of IE and Safari for MacOS

https://caniuse.com/input-inputmode

2 - Custom font to mask text

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/noppa/text-security/master/dist/text-security.css">
<style>
    input.password-mask {
        font-family: "text-security-disc";
        -webkit-text-security: disc;
    }
</style>
<input type="tel" class="password-mask" />
```

This solution has the benefit of wider browser coverage Safari and IE11 however might be less secure as won't use the browser security features for type=password.

Git repo - https://github.com/noppa/text-security

Demo - https://noppa.github.io/text-security.html

Answer (score 1):

Firefox, IE don't support -webkit-text-security property.
for more details, you can visit on this link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a PWA using React. (And using Material-UI and Formik on the component in question, so syntax may seem a bit unusual...)

I'm not totally clear on the OP's goals... but it seems similar to my needs:
I'm using "disc" and needing a "number" keyboard as well.

I wanted to stop Chrome from trying to save login credentials (because devices are shared with many users in my situation).

For the input (MUI TextField in my case), I set the **type** to **"text"** rather than "password" in order to get around Chromes detection for the store-credentials-feature. I made **input-mode** as **"numeric"** to get the keypad to pop up as the keyboard.
And then, as Richa described, I used **text-security: disc;** and **-webkit-text-security: disc;**
Again, careful of my code's syntax, as it's using React, MUI, etc. (React uses capital letters and no dashes, etc.)

See the parts with the // comment; the rest is just bonus for context.

```
<TextField
            type="text" // this is a hack so Chrome does not offer saved credentials; should be "password" otherwise
            name="pincode"
            placeholder="pin"
            value={values[PIN_FIELD]}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <RemoveRedEye
                    color="action"
                    onClick={togglePasswordMask}
                  />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
              inputProps: {
                inputMode: 'numeric', // for number keyboard
                style: {
                  textSecurity: `${passwordIsMasked ? 'disc' : ''} `, // part of hack described above. this disc mimics the password *** appearance
                  WebkitTextSecurity: `${passwordIsMasked ? 'disc' : ''} `, // same hack
                },
              },
            }}
          />
```

As you can see, I have a toggle that lets you hide or show the pin (by clicking the eye icon). A similar function could be added as appropriate / desired.

```
const [passwordIsMasked, setPasswordIsMasked] = useState(true)
const togglePasswordMask = () => {
setPasswordIsMasked((value) => !value)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-text-security` works in Firefox since version 114 which was released in June 2023.