# How to make a textbox content as DOTS while typing and retrieving data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to mask a textbox in our application. But we can't use Textmod=Password because if we used `Textmode=Password` we can't retrieve the data in edit mode and we can't return the data to textbox affter saving. Here I want to make a textbox content as dots while typing and want to retrieve typed content as dots in that textbox. 
I just tried this code

```
-webkit-text-security: disc;-moz-text-security: disc;text-security: disc;
```

This code worked in Chrome but it doesn't work in either IE or Firefox.

How can i achieve the same results in IE and Firefox this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [-webkit-text-security compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822682/webkit-text-security-compatibility)

Comment: while you are editing, the data should be in dot format?

Comment: @publicFileResultDuser3230921 ya i want data in dot format while editing also. here i used this
" -webkit-text-security: disc;-moz-text-security: disc;text-security: disc;  "
but this worked in chrome. but not IE and firefox. I want to make this in IE and Firefox also.

Comment: @MehmetErenYener but how.??

Comment: try something like this and handle remaining drawbacks
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3hbrmnz/2/)

Comment: @publicFileResultDuser3230921 we can't use jquery because its an old project. can you make it through javascript..?? my application is in asp .net(framework 2.0) . Can you please do it using javascript..???

Comment: @salmanrathore - what advantage does this present over just using a an `input[type=password]` element? You most certainly can retrieve text from a password field in javascript, just as can you assign text to one. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q7rL4dft/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this.You can change the text attribute after getting the values in text box.

[Degrading -webkit-text-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822548/degrading-webkit-text-security)

Answer (score 0):

Use This and you will get it.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
UserName
<input type="text" name="fname"/>
Password
<input type="password" name="lname"/>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is what will come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I62LJ.png)

Comment: As OP said in his question, he can't use this.