# How can I disable browser save password prompt in all browsers throughout the application?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

How can i disable save password prompt from all the browser?

I have tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775342/how-to-disable-chromes-saved-password-prompt-setting-through-javascript) way but this is not working for me because by setting input type text is a security reason and also this works only on Chrome and Firefox(Moz) I need it in all browsers. **is it possible to disable browser save password prompt ?**
one can help me in this issue?

Comment: Check this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here you go!
with help of [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822682/webkit-text-security-compatibility)

```
 window.onload = function() {
        init();  }

    function init() {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
        console.log(style);

        if (style.webkitTextSecurity) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            x.setAttribute("type", "password");
        } }
```

**CSS**

```
 input {
        text-security: disc;
        -webkit-text-security: disc;
        -moz-text-security: disc;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not change this functionality because it is not JavaScript that is performing those prompts, regardless of the browser. Each browser has their own implementation of this "Save Password" functionality and none of them expose it to JavaScript, as that could be a potential security risk.

There are a few different "hacks" (such as the one that you linked) that will work sometimes, but they are not guaranteed and there is no cross-browser implementation that will do what you are requesting.