# Obfusacting text using css

Tags: css

Is there a standard alternative to `-webkit-text-security`
as I want to apply password disc like display to other elements apart from input fields

```
-webkit-text-security: disc;
```

Comment: Use a font that contain only a disc character

Comment: can you provide example font?

Comment: keep in mind that using a font will not protect from a copy/paste. Copying the text and pasting it elsewhere will show the real text.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I just wanted the property for displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an alternative for `-webkit-text-security` you should use custom fonts like [text-security](https://github.com/noppa/text-security). But if you have concerns about cross browsing or browsers that do not support `-webkit-text-security` you should check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823310/11908502).