# IE support for flipping input type between 'password' and 'text'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

For usability reasons, I want to add a checkbox to my login form that allows the user to t
toggle the masking of the password field.

---

### Sample Code

The basic code I've got for this is as follows (***this is quick mockup code, not tested in anything other than Chrome Canary***):

**HTML**

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="somepassword" />
<input type="checkbox" name="unmask" id="unmask" />
```

​
**JavaScript**

```
var password = document.getElementById('password'),
    chkbox = document.getElementById('unmask');
        
        
chkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  password.type = e.currentTarget.checked ? 'text' : 'password';
});
```

**JSFiddle**

[See the above code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/qsPdP/).

---

Whilst the above concept seems to work perfectly well, when you look at the code that would flip the `type` attribute in [jQuery's source code](http://bit.ly/jqsource) you see a comment as follows:-

> // We can't allow the type property to be changed (since it causes problems in IE)

This added to a similar quote I've seen elsewhere on StackOverflow...

> As of Microsoft Internet Explorer 5, the type property is read/write-once, but only when an input element is created with the createElement method and before it is added to the document.

...appear to indicate that the above code is a no-go for Internet Explorer.

What I want to know is; is this the case? If so is this only a problem for IE7/8, etc? Is there any further, official documentation on this.

Comment: > *is this the case?* You seem to have found this is the case, didn't you? FYI here's the jQuery ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1957

Comment: @RoatinMarth as per MitchS's comment it would appear not, its inconstant so wanted to understand the reasons - thanks for the link which helps.

Comment: [MSDN docs for input 'type' property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534700%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @IHateLazy this is no longer true as of IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not allow you to change the attribute type of an input field.

Workaround:

```
<div id="container">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="somepassword" />
<input type="text" name="passwordtext" id="passtext" value="somepassword" style="display:none;" />
<input type="checkbox" name="unmask" id="unmask" />
</div>
```

use jQuery, not raw Javascript. In IE, there is no addEventListener, just attachEvent(thanks to the brilliant people at Microsoft). Bind event listeners properly.

```
$('#unmask').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#password').hide();
        $('#passtext').show();
};
});
```

Comment: IE9 and above will let you change the type of an input field.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. Thought you should get that one back.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on IE. Every time when you want to switch between these two types you have to create new input and replace it with the old one. This is the only solution for IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the known issue just check other forums and answers.

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/190995/change-input-type-in-ie
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987788/javascript-ie6-7-8-change-input-type

if it is the case you can use `.replaceWith();`.

```
chkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var $clone = $("password").clone();
  $clone.attr("type", e.currentTarget.checked ? 'text' : 'password');
  $("password").replaceWith($clone);
});
```

For the same reason `$clone.attr` might not work so you can also try creating object from password exluding type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with alex23 about the event binding use jQuery for it.