# How to trigger two effects on a single event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want these two effects to take place without using a function, is there any syntax ?

`onkeypress="this.value=(this.value=='Password')?'' : this.value"`

`onkeypress="this.type='password'"`

Comment: a) put them in the same handler b) use two handler by [attaching them properly](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

Comment: tell me the way @Bergi

Comment: You should simply use `<input type="password" placeholder="Password">`

Comment: lol it solves my problem though, I still want to know is there a way to do in that manner ?

Comment: Why do you need to change the `type` to `password` on every keypress?  It's not going to change back once you've set it.

Comment: just use a semicolon `;`

Comment: you are right @robertc , if you learn a way to make it happen using some events do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="password" placeholder="Password">` will be better suited for what you are trying to do. However, to answer your question: Just put both statements in the same handler:

```
onkeypress="if (this.value=='Password') this.value = ''; this.type = 'password';"
```

Notice that you will get [problems with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987788/javascript-ie6-7-8-change-input-type) which does not allow changing the `type` of an input element. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004329/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

Hey good question.

```
onclick="checkPassword();"
```

then have a JavaScript (with what Bergi mentioned):

```
var pw = document.getElementById("password");

if (pw.value=='Password') pw.value = ''; pw.type = 'password';
```

HTML:

```
<input type="password" id="password"/>
```

Comment: thanx but i mentioned no functions, while its almost the same that bergi answered in the other means.

Comment: Because i knew how to work with functions, anyways placeholder is better @Bergi